# JDO - Determine entities affected by transaction commit

Tags: java, jdo

I'm in the early stages of putting together a Java web project with a `JDO` based persistence layer and I found myself wondering about this.

If I start a transaction in my `HTTPServlet` and `commit` or `rollback` in the servlet before writing the response to the output stream, is there a way to get a list of objects (or just IDs) that were changed by the commit? If so, what would the performance be like?

Update:

I haven't tried this yet, but it seems that adding an `InstanceLifecycleListener` to the `PersistenceManager` would do the trick.

Comment: What about PM.getManagedObjects() ? or a JDO-provider specific way? (which one?)

Comment: PM.getManagedObjects() doesn't only return the objects that are changed. The InstanceLifecycleListener isn't JDO-provider specific, which is nice, and should work. Once I've had a chance to test it, I'll update with more questions or an answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding an `InstanceLifecycleListener` to the `PersistenceManager` is working nicely so far. The only gotcha was not to omit the `Classes[]` parameter to `addInstanceLifecycleListener`. Instead if you want to listen to all changes, pass `null` explicitly.